# How can i implement a button in a fragment without crashing the app?

Tags: java, android

I have three fragments in a menu and one of them is the page where I perform the "itu" calculation. When I leave the part corresponding to this uncommented, my app crashes when I click the button.
Below are the codes for my xml and fragment class:

Java class:

```
public class CalculoFragment extends Fragment {
String temperaturastr;
String umidadestr;

EditText temperatura;
EditText umidade;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculo, container, false);


    Button botaocalcular = view.findViewById(R.id.botaocalcular);
    botaocalcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            calculo(view);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void calculo(View view){
    temperatura = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextTemp);
    umidade = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextUmid);

    temperaturastr = temperatura.getText().toString();
    umidadestr = umidade.getText().toString();

    double temperaturavalor = Double.parseDouble(temperaturastr);
    double umidadevalor = Double.parseDouble(umidadestr);
    double itu=(0.8 * temperaturavalor + (umidadevalor / 100) * (temperaturavalor - 14.4) + 46.4);

            if (itu < 72) {
                Intent confortotermicoact = new Intent(getActivity(), ConfortoTermicoActivity.class);
            startActivity(confortotermicoact);
            }
            if (itu >= 72 && itu < 80){
                Intent brandoact = new Intent(getActivity(), BrandoActivity.class);
            startActivity(brandoact);
            }
            if (itu >= 80 && itu < 90){
                Intent moderadoact = new Intent(getActivity(), ModeradoActivity.class);
            startActivity(moderadoact);
            }
            if (itu >= 90 && itu <= 98){
                Intent severoact = new Intent(getActivity(), SeveroActivity.class);
            startActivity(severoact);
            }
```

XML:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="377dp"

    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:text="Para começar, insira os dados abaixo:"
    android:textColor="@color/azul"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.099" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Temperatura do Ar:"
    android:textColor="@color/azul"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.077"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.31" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextUmid"
    android:layout_width="293dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:hint="Umidade Relativa do Ar"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="@color/azul"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.135"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.559" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botaocalcular"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:background="@color/azul"
    android:text="CALCULAR O ESTRESSE TÉRMICO"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.412"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.852">

</Button>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Umidade Relativa do Ar:"
    android:textColor="@color/azul"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.102"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.503" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTemp"
    android:layout_width="309dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:hint="Temperatura do Ar"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="@color/azul"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.156"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.365"
    />
```

Please help me, I've tried everything and I can't get it to work.

Comment: What is the actual exception and stacktrace from the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to find the view from the fragment layout when you click a button. You have to do that on `onCreateView()`.

The view that you are passing on `calculo()` is not the fragment.

So, `view.findViewById(R.id.editTextTemp)` and the other `findViewById()` that are on `calculo()` shouldn't be there, put them on `onCreateView()`.